# Return a *class name*

Tags: python

In python what does it mean for a method to return a *class name*?

What I mean is suppose you have two classes:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, board=[]):
        """(TestClass, int) -> NoneType
        """
        self.board = [(0, [5,4,3,2,1]), (1, []), (2, []), (3, [])]

    def top_coin(self, idx):
        """(TestClass, int) -> Coin

        Return's a Coin.

        """
        if not self.board[idx][1]:
            return None
        return self.board[idx][1][-1]

class Coin:

    def __init__(self, length):
        """(Coin, int) -> NoneType

        >>> c = Coin(3)
        >>> c.length
        3

        """
        self.length = length

    def __repr__(self):
        """(Coin) -> str
        """
        return "Coin(" + str(self.length) + ")"
```

and you want the method top_coin from class TestClass to return a Coin. Does that mean whatever it return should be wrapped around with the Coin class? So when doing

```
t1 = TestClass()
t1.top_coin(0)
Coin(1) ??
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to return a specific named class because the docstring claims it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you must return an instance of type `Coin`. For example:

```
class TestClass:
    ...
    def top_coin(self, size):
        ...
        return Coin(3) # you may change the parameter '3'
```

So when you call that method, you can store it as a variable of type `Coin`:

```
a_coin = t1.top_coin(0)
```

Also, in the `__init__` method of class `Coin` you have not declared `length`. It will cause an error.